# spring bacth with spring boot startup error with postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch-admin

I am actually trying to start the spring boot application which has a batch job configured.
I am getting the following error when I configure `postgres` in `application.properties` and add dependency, If I use embedded `H2 db` then the flow is working fine, If any one could help I will be greatful.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2019-01-03 12:24:55.675  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.javainuse.SpringBatchApplication     : Starting SpringBatchApplication on chnmct371583D with PID 8780 (D:\Git_verizon_2\references\jcl-poc\springboot-batch\target\classes started by lokeshkumar.r in D:\Git_verizon_2\references\jcl-poc\springboot-batch)
2019-01-03 12:24:55.692  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.javainuse.SpringBatchApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-03 12:24:57.040  INFO 8780 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ab3189c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-03 12:24:57.060  INFO 8780 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$15436d10] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-03 12:24:57.115  INFO 8780 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e309229f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-03 12:24:57.329  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-01-03 12:24:57.633  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-01-03 12:24:58.870  INFO 8780 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2019-01-03 12:24:58.891  INFO 8780 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2019-01-03 12:25:00.696  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.javainuse.SpringBatchApplication     : Started SpringBatchApplication in 5.803 seconds (JVM running for 6.428)
2019-01-03 12:25:00.698  INFO 8780 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2019-01-03 12:25:00.806  INFO 8780 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-03 12:25:00.826  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-01-03 12:25:00.877  INFO 8780 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-01-03 12:25:00.885 ERROR 8780 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.javainuse.SpringBatchApplication.main(SpringBatchApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:768) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:204) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:85) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.getJobExecutions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:266) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:213) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:186) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:172) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '' as a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: no such class found
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["map"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1635) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1187) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:44) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:70) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:322) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties file looks like

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

My pom file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-batch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBatch</name>
    <description>Spring Batch-Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-task.version>1.2.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-task.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-task.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: In your stacktrace I see a line `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.getJobExecutions(Unknown Source)`. Do you have a method named `getJobExecutions` anywhere ? If yes please provide the code

Comment: which version of postgres are you using. For 9.2 and later, you should use org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect instead.

Comment: kindly share your entity class also, 'cause i'm seeing some id related exception.

Comment: @Jabongg I am using postgres version 10

Comment: @samvel1024 I have not used any method name getIJobExecutions

Comment: kindly see if this helps you here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239413/de-serializing-json-to-polymorphic-object-model-using-spring-and-jsontypeinfo-an

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with some data in the spring-batch created  table e.g. `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION`, etc. When I created a new database, the issue was resolved.